# In Linux how do I display all files that are of 3-uppercase character file names?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

For example, it should display
ABC.txt
123.c
KIA.py

Comment: How is `abc` or `kia` uppercase? Do you mean lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this in any language, but it is pretty simple in python:

```
import os

for f in os.listdir("."):
    parts = f.split(".")
    if len(parts[0]) == 3 and parts[0] == parts[0].upper():
        print(f)
```

keep in mind the limitation that this is will also print XYZ.something.txt if that was in your `cd` I don't know if that would be desirable or not.

the explanation is pretty simple...

if f was XYZ.txt then parts would be a list of ["XYZ",txt]... so then you check to see if the length of the first string is 3 and that it is the same if you transform it to uppercase...

Answer (score 0):

With pure bash:

```
# set some shell options
shopt -u nocaseglob
shopt -s globasciiranges
# ls away!
ls [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*
```

Here's [the bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) for shell options

Comment: `[A-Z]` does not include `123.c`

Comment: since when is 123 uppercase?

Comment: It's mentioned as a requirement in the question.

Comment: I assumed that was also a mistake (given the original question)